# Using Twitter api url to tweet

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, rest-client, oauth-1.0a

`LinkedIn api` provides access token to use it in url to post a message which uses `oauth2` in `Rest client`. So by using the `url` in my application, i can post the message.

`Twitter api` uses `oauth1` to tweet by accepting `parameter`.But the problem is `timestamp,nounce,oauth_signature parameters` gets auto generated and keep on changing for every request in `Rest client`.Here url is not sufficient to tweet, it need parameters but 3 parameters keep on changing on Rest client.

I tried to pass every parameter in url, it throws

```
 error: code 32, could not authenticate you
```

i am dependent only on url to send a tweet.My application supports parameters too but three parameters are auto generating.I cant auto generate bcz i am hardcoding it in my application.

Is there any solution to tweet by using url?

Is there any way to make those 3 parameters fixed?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what's going on here. Perhaps you could post more of the code and what you expected to happen?

By definition the `nonce` is a number only used once, and shouldn't be hardcoded. The timestamp also should reflect the current time on each request.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce